# How to compare string to an integer?

Tags: string, batch-file, comparison, integer

I have this:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set bla="-666"
set zzz="333"
if !zzz! LSS !bla! echo lesser
pause
```

Gives me "lesser" which is wrong. I know this is because of the ASCII values. But what is the way around to compare them as if they are numbers?

**EDIT:**

Some more codes:

```
set mn=99999
for /f "tokens=1-9" %%a in (%%g) do (
set zzz=%%d
)
if "!zzz!" LSS "!mn!" set mn=!zzz!
```

None of the answers below gave me the correct result so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, removing the quotes and then comparing.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set bla="-666"
set zzz="333"
for %%a in (!bla!) do set /a bla=%%~a+0
for %%a in (!zzz!) do set /a zzz=%%~a+0
echo !bla! !zzz!
if !bla! LSS !zzz! (
    echo lesser
) else (
    echo greater
)   
pause
```

Comment: This is not a very robust way to remove quotes (consider an empty string `bla=""`). You'd rather do it with a `for`-loop, like so: `for %%a in (!bla!) do set /a bla=%%~a+0`.

Comment: @EitanT You are correct. Using for is safer for the general case when variable can be empty ("") or without quotes. Since my answer was selected I edit it.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
@echo off
set bla=-666
set zzz=333
if %zzz% LSS %bla% echo lesser
pause >nul
```

No need for quotes or delayed expansion.

Comment: Yes it works. However in my case bla and zzz variables are returned by parsing a string, so they are string too. If I directly compare them, what it exactly does is what I showed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking incorrect use of the blackquotes when setting a var, the VAR="CONTENT" are only for special cases, but not this.

```
@echo off
set /A "bla=-666"
set /A "zzz=333"
if %zzz% LSS %bla% echo lesser
pause
```

Notice i've used blackquotes to enclose the variable, the content don't have any blackquote.

And remember too to NOT use blackquotes in the comparision when comparing numbers, like this:

```
if "%zzz%" LSS "%bla%" echo lesser
```

Comment: When I use set /A "zzz=%%e" it fails?

Comment: What you mean with "it fails"? with a comparision with...what? or what? remember you can only set numbers with the aritmetic operator (/A) if you try to set characters, it fails (the num goes to 0).

Comment: I was somehow unable to use set /a bla=!final! it says missing operator. Without /a it doesn't give any error but not doing what I want.